# Isotope filter function returning 0 for Element Item

Tags: javascript, jquery-isotope

I am using the vanilla JS version of Isotope to create a filter function like so

```
isotope.arrange({
    filter: function(element) {
        console.log(element)
```

However, the value returned for the variable element is 0 and not an HTMLElement like it is on my local machine.

When logging the isotope.getItemElements() beforehand it returns all the items so I know it has been instantiated correctly.

Any Help would be much appreciated

Test case: https://codepen.io/matthewattanasio/pen/qBOjeMr

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So I think the documentation is not correct https://isotope.metafizzy.co/filtering.html#functions states the following

```
iso.arrange({
  // item element provided as argument
  filter: function( itemElem ) {
    var number = itemElem.querySelector('.number').innerText;
    return parseInt( number, 10 ) > 50;
  }
});
```

However in my test case https://codepen.io/matthewattanasio/pen/qBOjeMr the filter function has two arguments and its the second argument that returns the element e.g. the above code should actually be

```
iso.arrange({
  // item element provided as argument
  filter: function( itemElem1, itemElem2 ) {
    var number = itemElem2.querySelector('.number').innerText;
    return parseInt( number, 10 ) > 50;
  }
});
```